# "..mit dessen Geldbeutel." Can someone explain this usage?

Tags: grammatical-case

My local newspaper in Bayern mentions an attack on a 63 year-old man and reports

> Das Opfer wurde dabei verletzt, die Täter flüchteten mit dessen
> Geldbeutel.

I have never seen the preposition "mit" followed by the genitive before. I understand the phrase to mean "they fled with his wallet" but then wouldn't it have been better, to write:

> ....., die Täter flüchteten mit seinem Geldbeutel.?

Comment: Did you transcribe the first word in mistake or does it really say "Der Opfer" rather than correctly neuter nominative "Das Opfer" for the subject?

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected both the gender and the repitition of dessen. To reiterate, my problem is understanding how a genitive (dessen) follows the preposition mit which is normally followed by a dative.

Comment: If you replace the Demonstrativpronomen "dessen" with what it actually demonstrates - "das Opfer" - then it becomes clearer: "...mit dem Geldbeutel des Opfers". "des Opfers" is Genitiv like in English it would be possessive "...with the victims purse".

Answer (score 4):

> Der Täter flüchtete mit seinem Geldbeutel

could mean the offender fled with *their own* purse (not making a lot of sense in this context, obviously - after all, a robbery was reported, but still ambiguous)

The paper  wanted to make the facts completely clear and used the genitive

> ... der Täter flüchtete mit dessen Geldbeutel

("Geldbeutel" is still dative in this sentence! - its just attributed with "dessen" (thus genitive) to make the ownership clear) can only mean the offender fled with *the victim's* purse.

Take the English sentence

> The offender fled with the victim's purse

Same construct: the *purse* is dative, *victim's* possessive.

Both is correct, unambiguous only the latter sentence.

Comment: This seems to be an example of *der* as a demonstrative pronoun, with *dessen* being an inflected form. My understanding is that *der* can be used when the person/object referred to is clear from context, but *er* would not work because that would refer to the current subject. English does not use demonstrative pronouns that way; the closest parallel would be "the former/latter". So in English you actually have to spell out "the victim".

Answer (score 2):

*Dessen* (like *deren*) is an invariable determiner working as a possessive article and, as tofro stated, used in ambiguous contexts for disambiguation. Generally speaking, the possessive perspective is similar to that of the genitive. The genitive look of *dessen* just reflects the pure idea of "possession" of a masculine (or neuter) "possessor" like the genitive article *des*. Unlike the possessive article *sein* it doesn't have marks of case or number:

- *Er sprach mit einem Kollegen. **Dessen Frau** war kürzlich gestorben*. (nominative)
- *Er stellte mich seinem Cousin vor. **Dessen Frau** kannte ich bereits.* (accusative)
- *Er lernte auch den Personalchef kennen. Mit **dessen Frau** hatte er schon einmal zu tun gehabt.* (dative)
- *?Obwohl er sich wochenlang im Nachbarhaus von Herrn Müller aufhielt, war es ihm nicht gelungen, **dessen Frau** ansichtig zu werden.* (genitive)
- *Er sprach lange mit dem Juniorchef. **Dessen Kinder** waren gerade in einem Feriencamp.* (nominative plural)

In all these cases, *dessen* does **not** refer to the subject *er* in the first sentence but to the respective second person mentioned there.

If the reference item is feminine or plural, the corresponding determiner is *deren*:

- *Sie sprach mit ihrer Mutter. **Deren** Mann war im Krankenhaus.*
- *Sie saßen mit den Nachbarn im Garten. **Deren Kinder** waren an diesem Abend bei Freunden.*

All given sentences can be transformed into relative clauses using *dessen* or *deren* as a relative pronoun:

- *Er kam mit einem Kollegen, **dessen Frau** kürzlich gestorben war.*

As to invariability in case and number, you have the same grammatical characteristic with the interrogative article *wessen*:

- *Wessen Handschuh / Tasche / Buch ist das hier? Wessen Stifte sind das?*